# Twilio Client is not letting me search for UK National Phone Numbers

Tags: c#, twilio

I'm trying to retrieve UK National numbers using the Twilio Client, however this code:

```
        TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);
        
        var national = await NationalResource.ReadAsync(pathCountryCode: "GB", limit: 20);
```

Results in this error:

> Twilio.Exceptions.ApiException: 'The requested resource
> /2010-04-01/Accounts/[Redacted]/AvailablePhoneNumbers/GB/National.json
> was not found'

I have successfully managed to retrieve mobile numbers, using:

```
    TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);
    
    var mobile = await MobileResource.ReadAsync(contains: $"+447", pathCountryCode: "GB", limit: 20);
```

Looking at the docs, i cant see that National is listed, however its available to select using their TwilioClient and I can search for numbers on the Twilio 'Buy a number' page.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/phone-numbers/api/availablephonenumber-resource